# #define for pedagogical purposes

Tags: c

I would like to hide some complexity from some non-trivial code I'm writing. Here, I would like to hide one level of indirection from a struct pointer, to make it more readable. I'm not asking whether this is clean or a best practice or not, I know it isn't, but I also know what I like to achieve :)

So, how kosher is to have something like

```
#define getmark() m->o->marked
```

besides that fact that I would not write it in non-academic code? That would allow me to do

```
n->getmark()
```

, which is nicer (and more to the point than)

```
n->m->o->marked
```

Is the `#define` code correct? Will it just do a text replace here with no other strings attached?

Comment: makes me think the code actually C++ which is rather misleading

Comment: @DougT. You are correct. There is some pseudo-code that looks OOish, that's why I decided for the "method-looking" way. Maybe that's what you're seeing.

Comment: Off topic of the question, but this looks like a major Law of Demeter violation.

Comment: @EricAndres: I know nothing about that law, but as a C coder it certainly violates a lot of other best practices I know of... it's just that in this case, readability is more important than good SE practices.

Comment: A more C, OO approach would be to do `getMark(n);`. You define a set of functions that operate over whatever struct n is.

Comment: Making a variable look like a method is a terrible idea. I like @DougT.'s suggestion much better.

Comment: @EricAndres: LoD doesn't make sense at all here. What would you do? `m = get_m(n); o = get_o(m); marked = o->marked;`? This looks like major code bloat.

Comment: Pedagogical? Please don't teach this way of abusing macros.

Comment: @netcoder I realized after writing that this is C, not C++. LoD would apply if this were object oriented. But following 3 pointers to get a value should be encapsulated in a method regardless of object orientedness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO, most C programmers would prefer a function-style macro, like:

```
#define getmark(m) ((m) && (m)->o ? (m)->o->marked : -1)
```

Comment: This still need outer parens, I think. Does `x = getmark(X) ? 5 : 4;` work as expected?

Comment: I don't think they will be needed, but they won't harm. Oops, I just checked. outer parentheses *are* needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Quite frankly - not.

You are not making your code eaiser to read, but instead hiding the fact that there is a hidden state machine  (m pointer which points to o).

You also make this hack global - which might break if someone has such variables.

Also ... the trick of adding "()" after the macro to make it look like you are calling a normal function, instead of 2 indirections... is bad. It looks for a reader like there should be a function with this name, but instead you hide a monster (poker face....).

If you need to simplify the state machine, and you know that there will be only one state - create a global static variable and create plain functions to call those objects.

Answer (score 1):

It will work, but even in C it's a terrible idea. Please don't do it.

If you want to avoid the 'source bloat' of repeated indirections, use a temporary pointer.

```
O* myO;

myO = n->m->o;

o->marked = o->this + o->that;
```

Comment: Yes, but this is a concurrent data structure, I'd be really, *really* scared to use a tmp pointer or anything else, really. But I agree, but I can't :)

Comment: If something can change your structure when you use a tmp, something can change it when you chain your `->` derefs. One statement does not imply thread-safe, @Dervin.

Comment: @DervinThunk Your #define doesn't change any of the concurrency issues. the compiler is likely to optimise it any way it likes.

Answer (score 0):

A problem with your original macro is that

```
n->getmark() = 123;
```

will work while it should not.